# $K_3$ subgraph in a random graph

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a random graph of $n$ vertices where the probability
    of there being an edge between any two vertices is .01. I want to
    see what is the asymptotic behavior of the probability that there
    exists a cycle of length 3 within this graph. I understand that
    the number of ways I can have a cycle of length 3 is $\binom{n}{3},$
    and the probability of their being a cycle between a given set of
    3 vertices is $(.01)^3.$ However, I am not quite sure where to go
    with this particular probability. Any assistance will be greatly
    appreciated.

Comment: I think the probability distribution is irrelevant all such graphs are isomorphic.

Comment: It is a lot easier to find the expected number of triangles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected number of triangles in a random graph of size $n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730294/expected-number-of-triangles-in-a-random-graph-of-size-n)

Comment: @JMoravitz: Isn't the expected number of triangles, found in that earlier question, easier to compute (by linearity of expectation) than the probability of at least one triangle?  Such I take to be the significance of dREaM's Comment.

Answer (score 1):

First I guess your random graph model is usually indicated with $G(n,p)$, which is called a Binomial Random graph with $n$ vertices and each edge is selected independently with probability $p$.

If $n\geq 3$ then the probability that a random graph G(n,0.01) contains $C_3$ as an induced subgraph is positive, let's say it is $r>0$. Since $V(G)$, the vertex set of $G$, contains $\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor$ disjoint subsets of $3$ vertices each, the probability that no induced subgraph of G is isomorphic to $C_3$ is at most $(1-r)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor}$ which tends to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Hence as  $n \rightarrow \infty$, almost every graph $G(n,0.01)$ contains $C_3$ as a induced subgraph.