# Number of house subgraphs in a Erdős-Rényi graph?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, expected-value, random-graphs

Considering we have a "house subgraph", which is a graph composed of 5 nodes, $v_1, \ldots v_5$ in which the edges
$\{v_1,v_2\}, \{v_1,v_3\}, \{v_2,v_3\}, \{v_2,v_4\}, \{v_3,v_5\}, \{v_4,v_5\}$ exist, and no other edge between them exists
(see Figure below). What is the expected number of house subgraphs in a random graph according
to $G(n, p)$ (Erdős-Rényi graph with $n$ vertices and edge probability $p$)?

House subgraph figure:

[image]

Comment: subscripts: use `$v_1, \ldots v_5$`, e.g., to get $v_1 \ldots v_5$.  Subscript `x_n`, exponents `x^n`

Comment: @MishaLavrov I edited the question. You're right!

Comment: Hi OP, on this website, you are generally expected to show your work to receive an answer. If you have no idea where to start, you might find finding the expected number of triangles (it is discussed here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658600/the-expected-number-of-triangles-in-erdos-renyi-graph-why-wrong-derivation-als) to be a good starting point. Your problem is a bit harder (there are many ways to make a house using 5 vertices, whereas only one way to make a triangle out of three) but hopefully should help.

Comment: Another good question you can try to answer as a starting point: how many house subgraphs does $K_5$ (the complete graph with $5$ vertices) have? (From there, you can ask the same question about $K_n$, and from there you can ask about the probability that each of them "survives" in $G_{n,p}$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's solve a more general problem:

> Suppose $\Gamma$ is a graph with $m$ vertices and $k$ edges. What is the expected number of induced subgraphs isomorphic to $\Gamma$ in $G(n, p)$ ($n$-vertex Erdos-Renyi random graph with edge probability $p$)?

Let's solve it first for the case, where $n = m$. Then there is only one induced subgraph of size $m$ in our random graph. What is the probability of it being isomorphic to $\Gamma$?

There are $m!$ bijections from its vertices to the vertices of $\Gamma$, but only $\frac{m!}{|Aut(\Gamma)|}$ are distinct in respect to automorphisms of $\Gamma$. For all those distinct bijections the events of them being isomorphisms are disjoint and probability of each of them equals $p^k (1 - p)^{\frac{m(m-1)}{2} - k}$. Thus the total probability of $G(m, p)$ being isomorphic to $\Gamma$ is $\frac{m! p^k (1 - p)^{\frac{m(m-1)}{2} - k}}{|Aut(\Gamma)|}$.

Now assume $n$ is arbitrary. For any $m$-element set $A$ of vertices of our random graph assume $I_A$ to be the Bernoulli random variable that equals $1$ if induced subgraph on those vertices is isomorphic to $\Gamma$ and $0$ otherwise. Then, due to linearity of expectation, the expected number of induced subgraphs isomorphic to $\Gamma$ is the sum of expected values of all $I_A$. We have already found, that the expectation of each of them (equal to their probability to be $1$) is $\frac{m! p^k (1 - p)^{\frac{m(m-1)}{2} - k}}{|Aut(\Gamma)|}$. And the number of $m$-element subsets of vertices to which they correspond is $C_n^m = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$.

Thus, the answer is

$$\frac{n!p^k (1 - p)^{\frac{m(m-1)}{2} - k}}{(n-m)!|Aut(\Gamma)|}$$

Now you can calculate the corresponding numbers for your specific case (i.e. the number of vertices, edges and automorphisms of the "house graph") and put them into this formula.