# Finding the total number of triangle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to calculate the number of triangles in a simple graph. I am totally aware of the upper bound for a complete graph $K_n$.  That is, the number of ways of choosing three vertices is
$$
\binom{n}{3}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}\sim\frac{n^3}{6}\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$
That's $O(n^3)$ is the bound for the number of triangles. I do have also an idea about how to calculate the expected number of triangles in a random graph. But the issue that I am facing is how to formulate the number of triangles in a simple graph i.e by taking simple examples and then generalising it. I went through this question: [minimum number of triangles in a simple graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654408/minimum-number-of-triangles-in-a-simple-graph) it was quite insightful but still, I am not able to succeed. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: I can't imagine there's any kind of useful formula for this. You could have two graphs that differ only in one edge but have very different numbers of triangles.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I agree even I'm trying to come up with a formula by adding one by one  vertices but no luck yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730294/expected-number-of-triangles-in-a-random-graph-of-size-n

Comment: Trace of the cube of the adjacency matrix divided by 6?

Comment: @YipJungHon Yup I am aware of the method used in the link provided by you. Since I mentioned in the question I'm aware of how to calculate expected number of triangles

Comment: @Casteels hmmm...I am actually aware of the adjacency matrix but I had no idea that you can use it for calculating the number of triangles. Could you mind elaborating on your take?

Answer (score 3):

The adjacency matrix is
$$A=[a_{ij}]$$
where $a_{ij}=1$ if and only if ${i,j} \in E;$ Otherwise $a_{ij}=0.$

The entries of $A^2=[a’_{ij}]$ are
$$
a’_{ij}=\sum_{k \in V} a_{ik} a_{kj}
$$
which counts the number of length 2 paths from $i$ to $j$ but double counts since the graph is undirected.

The entries of $A^3=[t_{ij}]$ are
$$
t_{ij}=\sum_{k \in V} a_{ik} a’_{kj}
$$
which counts the number of length 3 paths from $i$ to $j$. The trace of $A^3$ sums the number of triangles except all 3 permutations of triangle $\{i,j,k\}$ appear. Thus the overcount factor is $6.$